# Windows Phone 8.1 - Geoposition.Coordinate.Speed.Value vs Geoposition.Coordinate.Speed

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, geopositioning

What is the difference between

```
Geoposition.Coordinate.Speed.Value
```

and

```
Geoposition.Coordinate.Speed
```

?

Both seem to give me current speed but I'm wondering which one I should use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Geoposition.Coordinate.Speed` is of the type having `HasValu`e and `Value` properties
Whereas `Geoposition.Coordinate.Speed.Value` has just a double value type so you would need to store it accordingly and retrieve the values using properties needed.